# How to make mesh lights work in Blender Eevee?

Tags: light, eevee-render-engine

The closest I can get to making mesh lights affect their environment in Blender Eevee is giving them an *Emission* material and turning on "*Bloom*". But this isn't emitting proper light, it just looks like it is, but it doesn't light the surroundings whatsoever.

[image]

I would like to be able to light a scene with meshes without having to put point lamps everywhere just to make them emit light.

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/101244/does-the-blender-eevee-rendering-engine-really-have-indirect-lighting/101251#101251

Comment: Heres a tutorial Blender 2.8 EEVEE Tutorial How to Create Light from Emissive or Emission material the easy way https://youtu.be/kM3nKje-AX8

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Mesh lights can be used with EEVEE but they require an extra step to work: baking indirect light.

- Here is a scene with a *Light*-type object (correctly lighting a receiver plane) and two *Emission* meshes (currently doing nothing)

  [image]
- We should **add an *Irradiance Volume* object**, and make it encompass the volume that is affected by the light that we want to capture. This object has a *Resolution* option that should be adjusted depending on needs: the finer the grid, the most spatially accurate the description of the light in the scene.

  [image]
- To finish, in the *Scene* properties, under *Indirect Lighting*, we must **hit "*Bake Indirect Lighting*"**. This will compute how much diffuse light is bouncing around each one of the "dots" of the Irradiance grid.

  [image]

  Now the mesh lights are contributing to the lighting in the scene! Moreover, once the lighting is baked (and if the lights are not moved), objects can still be moved around and will be correctly lit by the baked light (they won't cast shadows though!):

  [image]

As far as I know, the Indirect Light cache doesn't have frames so the animation of mesh lights isn't possible at the moment.

---

**In the manual: [Irradiance Volumes](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/eevee/lightprobes/irradiance_volumes.html) - [Indirect Lighting Cache](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/eevee/indirect_lighting.html)**

Comment: One of the things that I most direly wanted to learn about Eevee. Hope they make it real-time some day.

Comment: Would it be possible to trigger the light baking from python on specific frames? (if the light changes position or intensity)

Comment: for moved objects to cast shadows the lights need to be re-baked or these lights produce no shadow at all?

Comment: They need to be re-baked