# Does the blender Eevee rendering engine really have indirect lighting?

Tags: rendering, lighting, eevee-render-engine

I heard that it does, and there is also a panel in the render settings that says "Indirect Lighting" but I never see any indirect lighting while I'm using Eevee, that's for sure.

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/99631/why-cant-i-make-mesh-lights-in-blender-eevee

Answer (score 9, accepted):

EEVEE uses [irradiance probes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/128162/how-do-the-new-light-probes-in-eevee-work) to calculate indirect lighting, it's not as accurate as pathtraced indirect lighting, but often is enough for realtime preview.

No indirect:
[image]

With irradiance volume:
[image]