# Eevee lighting scene issues

Tags: eevee-render-engine, lighting

I just made a spaceship scene where I set just one light (sun) from behind the spaceship as shown

[image]

but when I render it, it seems as if there are other lights in the scene as well, which isn't the case. The whole scene lights up

[image]

How do I alter the settings so as to achieve the above results in a render?

Comment: Any chance you added lights to your scene, but hid them? Hidden objects (including lights) still show in renders.

Comment: Have you baked your lighting?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Yes, I had a few hidden light sources. I got the right lighting done after deleting them. Thanks man.

Comment: @Nxdhin2005 I'm very new to blender. I gotta check out what baking is.

Comment: See this - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/128162/how-do-the-new-light-probes-in-eevee-work/128164#128164

Comment: Related -https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/186487/what-is-indirect-lighting-and-why-do-i-have-to-bake-it-in-eevee