# Magic texture with emission

Tags: node-editor, eevee-render-engine

This is a very nooby question but is there a way to have a (magic) texture with an emission (in EEVEE)?

[image]

Comment: if you have the image of that rainbow like texture, yes you can put it in your node setup as a emission

Comment: "*is there a way to have a (magic) texture with an emission?*" No, textures can't have "emission"s since emission is a shader property. "Can a texture (magic) be used in an emissive shader?" It sure can.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make mesh lights work in Blender Eevee?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/99631/how-to-make-mesh-lights-work-in-blender-eevee)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to go to the **node editor** and plug the texture into the color of the emission shader of your material.

You can control the strength of the emission shader in the node editor.

If you want the emission shader to light other objects, in Eevee the emission shader doesn't light other objects unless you add an **irradiance volume** (shift + A **->** Light probe **->** irradiance volume) and wrap the scene you want with it and then bake the **indirect lighting** in the render tab.