# Difference between light and emission shader

Tags: light

I got rectangle light source on the right and face with emission shader on the left. Viewport is set to "rendered" mode. As i understand on the right the light is visible, but it's source - is not. On the left - vice versa. How can i get both parameters visible?
[image]

Comment: You appear to be using the Eevee render engine. Eevee does not support mesh lights. Try changing your render engine to cycles, and they should both cast a light.

Comment: For more information on how to do this in eevee, see here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/99631/how-to-make-mesh-lights-work-in-blender-eevee

Comment: Right - it's Eevee. Thanks!