# how can i add emission (glow light) on logo

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials, node-editor, shaders

[image]
I am a new in blender and I have made this mobile device that have blue texture. And logo above it.But i cannot figure out that how to add light glow (emission) on logo.. Please guyz help me, this is my first project that i am working on it..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Cycles

Just plug image node ("Logo") color socket into **Emission** socket of **Principled BSDF** node. I added node Convertor > Math type **Multiply** to increase strenght of light.

If your logo image is not black&white use ColorRamp node, RGB Curve node or what ever that make it BW.

[image]

### Eevee

does not support mesh lights. But you can try distribute the light of emission texture by adding **Irradiance Volume** object. See [How to make mesh lights work in Blender Eevee?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/99631/how-to-make-mesh-lights-work-in-blender-eevee)

[image]