# Emission materials don't show any light

Tags: emission

I'm using an emission texture to use as a light, but it doesn't show anything. What could be wrong?
When a put Render mode (cycles) doesn't work eiter.

Light should be seen behind the TV. Thank you in advance

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: do you mean you want to see a halo as suggested by Christopher Bennett? Plus it looks like in your scene your light can't reflect on any surface...

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/164851

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking for backlight - ambient light behing a TV lightning a wall ...

- add **Area** light between TV and wall that works for Eevee and Cycles

Cycles
[image]

Eevee
[image]

Using emission material require Light Probe - **Irradiance Volume** for eevee engine that seems to be too short distance between emiter and receiver, so probably harder to setup.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go into your render properties settings, and enable "bloom", Also, depending on the quality of reflections you want, you also may want to use an irradiance volume and a reflection cubemap. The lighting must be baked after adding these. See image:

[image: EmissionBloom]

If you want to increase the emission strength beyond the default values provided in the Principled BSDF, provided you have a suitable image, you can connect it through an emission shader and a mix shader, and change the value from there. Be warned, however, any dark areas from the emission texture will darken the corresponding areas on the base texture. There are other ways to increase the strength if this is the case, but this is just a simple way to get stronger emissions for now.

[image]