# the emission of the lamp isn't working at all

Tags: emission

I am beginner in blender.

according to my toturial (grant abbit) I have to create an emission lamp in my project.I did what he had said. (make emission white and assign it...) .but it didn't work.what's wrong?

[image]

[image]

[image]

here is the blend file:
[image]

and this is the result (with light)
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/99631/how-to-make-mesh-lights-work-in-blender-eevee

Comment: you will have to use irradiance volume for this purpose. take a look at https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/99631/how-to-make-mesh-lights-work-in-blender-eevee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The emission value of the Principled BSDF isn't very strong, and in EEVEE emissive materials don't interact with volumetric materials anyway, in fact they don't cast light to other objects either. To get the desired result, you would have to place another spot lamp underneath the lamp like so:

[image: 1]

Comment: pleas have a look at the last picture (the result) .I want to change the color of the face (like you) but it is not working and it is gray :( and also have a look at torch .

Comment: You can change the color of the spot lamp directly, and copy that color over to the emissive material on the lamp post to be a bit more realistic. You can also swap out the Principled shader to an Emission shader to give off more visual light. In not sure what you want with the torch?

Comment: thanks it worked!

Answer (score 1):

You are in Eevee, and the emission shader lighting other things can only be done in cycles (or at least as far as I know).

Comment: yes .you are right and if I go into cycles mode the emission gets well.but in the toturial (I mean the first picture) , he(grant abbit) is in the Eevee mode.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. I don't know.

Comment: ok.no problem :)