# Emission material not visible in render

Tags: light, eevee-render-engine, emission

I am having a problem with the emission on this object. I have applied multiple materials to the mesh and emission is not visible. I have assigned the material to the selected parts of the object.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Eevee mesh lights are not supported directly, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/99631/how-to-make-mesh-lights-work-in-blender-eevee?answertab=votes#tab-top I would vote for duplication, but light ball should be white I guest. If issue persist attach blend with just a light ball. Thanks

Comment: ah ... one month later ... again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make mesh lights work in Blender Eevee?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/99631/how-to-make-mesh-lights-work-in-blender-eevee)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Maybe this option can be helpfull here