# How can I convert multiple faces of an object to light?

Tags: mesh, objects, light, eevee-render-engine, lighting

I have create this spiral LED lamp.
[image]

The cylindrical part of spiral has six faces.
[image]

Four of them (back) are the non-transparent part and the rest two (front) supposed to be the plastic cap of the LED strip.
[image]

At those front faces I have add a material with an emission surface so to look like lit LED strip.
[image]

What I want to do is to make all those front faces to shed light to my scene. But not just to look glowed like first image. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible, you just assign a material with emission shader to the faces that you want to emit light and they will(in Cycles render).
[image]

Comment: I have already done this at last step of my question and it just glow, doesn't give light to scene.

Comment: Hello @Simon :). You're using Eevee, which has [considerable limits](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/99631/78972) on mesh lights. You need to bake indirect light for them to light the environment (or use Cycles rendering engine).

Comment: Also, what do you expect the light to illuminate in your example? There is nothing around that can receive the light and it faces away from other parts of the object...

Comment: Hello @JachymMichal :). I know about Eevee limits, I just wanted to know if I can make an object, a face etc, to shed light like blender lights do!!!

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys in my example nothing, because what you see it's just isolated objects!!! :)