# why is the rendered view in cycles blurry but not in eevee

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

I've tried messing with a number of setting to get the rendered view to look decent using cycles but I gave up a while ago when I noticed switching to eevee was meeting my needs at the time. I am now trying to do some odd lighting similar to this post: [How can I convert multiple faces of an object to light?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/211181/how-can-i-convert-multiple-faces-of-an-object-to-light)

but I want to resolve the blurryness before I go down that path. At first glace it may seem they are similar but with cycles, but the most noticable thing are the edges have this pixelated choppy look, with everything being generally more blurry

I dont know which settings are relevant, but I have attached some screenshots.

With Cycles:
[image: With cycles]

With Eevee:
[image: With eevee]